# if my scanf variable is a float and a user inputs a character how can i prompt them to input a number? assuming the scanf is inside a do while loop

Tags: c, scanf

i have tried to use k = getchar() but it doesn't work too;

here is my code

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    float height;
    float k=0;
    do 
    {
        printf("please type a value..\n");
        scanf("%f",&height);
        k=height;
    }while(k<0);// i assume letters and non positive numbers are below zero.
    //so i want the loop to continue until one types a +ve float.
    printf("%f",k);



    return 0;
}
```

i want a if a user types letters or negative numbers or characters he/she should be prompted to type the value again until he types a positive number

Comment: Always check [what `scanf` *returns*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf#Return_value).

Comment: And read whole lines using [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) instead, and then use `sscanf` to parse the string. That will solve many problems.

Comment: Use `fgets()` to read user input and then see if that input successfully coverts to a `float`.  In either case, input is read.

Comment: it doesn't appear to read the character. it just goes into an endless loop if i type a character @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: The unwanted input remains in the input buffer, it is not discarded. But when using `fgets` as suggested and then `sscanf` you can easily dump the input line. You can also examine one input in different ways.

Comment: but i want a user to input a float not a string, fgets() is for asking for a string from a user.@chux.

Comment: Please read about `sscanf` which you apply to a string.

Comment: am new to programming and c is my first language haven't heard of sscanf even.

Comment: There is a whole family of `scanf` type functions to be used in different circumstance, but which broadly work the same. The learning curve (for a first language especially) can be steep.

Comment: read some thing about it from tutorialspoint but it seems you have to specify that the user is inputing a string or a character or an integer

Comment: can some one write a simple program for me as an example to prompt a user to type again if they input a letter until they input a positive number?

Comment: @kashumbushastephen Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service

Comment: @GovindParmar am not sure if i expressed my question well, is there any way you could help me identify how to tackle my problem. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Govind Parmar [already suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54370533/1475978), it is better/easier to use `fgets()` to read a full line of input, rather than use `scanf()` et al. for human-interactive input.

The underlying reason is that the interactive standard input is line-buffered by default (and changing that is nontrivial).  So, when the user starts typing their input, it is not immediately provided to your program; only when the user presses <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

If we do read each line of input using `fgets()`, we can then scan and convert it using [`sscanf()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sscanf.3.html), which works much like `scanf()`/`fscanf()` do, except that `sscanf()` works on string input, rather than an input stream.

Here is a practical example:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define  MAX_LINE_LEN  100

int main(void)
{
    char   buffer[MAX_LINE_LEN + 1];
    char  *line, dummy;
    double value;

    while (1) {

        printf("Please type a number, or Q to exit:\n");
        fflush(stdout);

        line = fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin);
        if (!line) {
             printf("No more input; exiting.\n");
             break;
        }

        if (sscanf(line, " %lf %c", &value, &dummy) == 1) {
             printf("You typed %.6f\n", value);
             continue;
        }

        if (line[0] == 'q' || line[0] == 'Q') {
             printf("Thank you; now quitting.\n");
             break;
        }

        printf("Sorry, I couldn't parse that.\n");
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The `fflush(stdout);` is not necessary, but it does no harm either.  It basically ensures that everything we have `printf()`'d or written to `stdout`, will be flushed to the file or device; in this case, that it will be displayed in the terminal.  (It is not necessary here, because standard output is also line buffered by default, so the `\n` in the printf pattern, printing a newline, also causes the flush.

I do like to sprinkle those `fflush()` calls, wherever I need to remember that at this point, it is important for all output to be actually flushed to output, and not cached by the C library.  In this case, we definitely want the prompt to be visible to the user before we start waiting for their input!

(But, again, because that `printf("...\n");` before it ends with a newline, `\n`, and we haven't changed the standard output buffering, the `fflush(stdout);` is not needed there.)

The `line = fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin);` line contains several important details:

- We defined the macro `MAX_LINE_LEN` earlier on, because `fgets()` can only read a line as long as the buffer it is given, and will return the rest of that line in following calls.

  (You can check if the line read ended with a newline: if it does not, then either it was the final line in an input file that does not have a newline at the end of the last line, or the line was longer than the buffer you have, so you only received the initial part, with the rest of the line still waiting for you in the buffer.)
- The `+1` in `char buffer[MAX_LINE_LEN + 1];` is because strings in C are terminated by a nul char, `'\0'`, at end.  So, if we have a buffer of 19 characters, it can hold a string with at most 18 characters.
- Note that NUL, or nul with one ell, is the name of the ASCII character with code 0, `'\0'`, and is the end-of-string marker character.

  NULL (or sometimes nil), however, is a pointer to the zero address, and in C99 and later is the same as `(void *)0`.  It is the sentinel and error value we use, when we want to set a pointer to a recognizable error/unused/nothing value, instead of pointing to actual data.
- `sizeof buffer` is the number of chars, total (including the end-of-string nul char), used by the variable `buffer`.

  In this case, we could have used `MAX_LINE_LEN + 1` instead (the second parameter to `fgets()` being the number of characters in the buffer given to it, *including* the reservation for the end-of-string char).

  The reason I used `sizeof buffer` here, is because it is so useful. (Do remember that if `buffer` was a pointer and not an array, it would evaluate to the size of a pointer; not the amount of data available where that pointer points to.  If you use pointers, you will need to track the amount of memory available there yourself, usually in a separate variable.  That is just how C works.)

  And also because it is important that `sizeof` is *not* a function, but an operator: it does not evaluate its argument, it only considers the size (of the type) of the argument.  This means that if you do something silly like `sizeof (i++)`, you'll find that `i` is *not* incremented, and that it yields the exact same value as `sizeof i`.  Again, this is because `sizeof` is an operator, not a function, and it just returns the size of its argument.
- `fgets()` returns a pointer to the line it stored in the buffer, or `NULL` if an error occurred.

  This is also why I named the pointer `line`, and the storage array `buffer`. They describe my intent as a programmer.  (That is very important when writing comments, by the way: do not describe what the code does, because we can read the code; but do describe your intent as to what the code should do, because only the programmer knows that, but it is important to know that intent if one tries to understand, modify, or fix the code.)
- The scanf() family of functions returns the number of successful conversions.  To detect input where the proper numeric value was followed by garbage, say `1.0 x`, I asked `sscanf()` to ignore any whitespace after the number (whitespace means tabs, spaces, and newlines; `'\t'`, `'\n'`, `'\v'`, `'\f'`, `'\r'`, and `' '` for the default C locale using ASCII character set), and try to convert a single additional character, `dummy`.

  Now, if the line does contain anything besides whitespace after the number, `sscanf()` will store the first character of that anything in `dummy`, and return 2.  However, because I only want lines that only contain the number and no dummy characters, I expect a return value of 1.
- To detect the `q` or `Q` (but only as the first character on the line), we simply examine the first character in `line`, `line[0]`.

  If we included `<string.h>`, we could use e.g. `if (strchr(line, 'q') || strchr(line, 'Q'))` to see if there is a `q` or `Q` anywhere in the line supplied.  The [`strchr(string, char)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strchr.3.html) returns a pointer to the first occurrence of char in string, or NULL if none; and all pointers but NULL are considered logically true.  (That is, we could equivalently write `if (strchr(line, 'q') != NULL || strchr(line, 'Q') != NULL)`.)

  Another function we could use declared in `<string.h>` is `strstr()`. It works like `strchr()`, but the second parameter is a string. For example, `(strstr(line, "exit"))` is only true if `line` has `exit` in it somewhere. (It could be `brexit` or `exitology`, though; it is just a simple substring search.)
- In a loop, `continue` skips the rest of the loop body, and starts the next iteration of the loop body from the beginning.
- In a loop, `break` skips the rest of the loop body, and continues execution after the loop.
- `EXIT_SUCCESS` and `EXIT_FAILURE` are the standard exit status codes `<stdlib.h>` defines.  Most prefer using `0` for EXIT_SUCCESS (because that is what it is in most operating systems), but I think spelling the success/failure out like that makes it easier to read the code.

Comment: thank you Nominal. this works but due to my level haven't figured out well how each of those functions are working together. 

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use `scanf`-family functions for reading from `stdin` in general.

`fgets` is better since it takes input as a string whose length you specify, avoiding buffer overflows, which you can later parse into the desired type (if any). For the case of `float` values, `strtof` works.

However, if the specification for your deliverable or homework assignment requires the use of `scanf` with `%f` as the format specifier, what you can do is check its return value, which will contain a count of the number of format specifiers in the format string that were successfully scanned:

> **§ 7.21.6.2**:
>
> The [scanf] function returns the value of the macro EOF if an input failure occurs
>   before the first conversion (if any) has completed. Otherwise, the function returns the
>   number of input items assigned, which can be fewer than provided for, or even zero, in
>   the event of an early matching failure.

From there, you can diagnose whether the input is valid or not.  Also, when `scanf` fails, `stdin` is not cleared and subsequent calls to `scanf` (i.e. in a loop) will continue to see whatever is in there. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7898215/how-to-clear-input-buffer-in-c) has some information about dealing with that.

Comment: is EOF the same as '\0' or its something different?

Comment: @kashumbushastephen `EOF` is an implementation defined macro that expands to an `int` with a negative value. It can be accessed by including `<stdio.h>`.

Comment: i think this question is still ahead in my learning course, cant really understand it.

Comment: Thank you all who have come up to shed light on this challenge, will continue to read more about all the suggestions you have suggested.